# Can I ping a specific site without DNS server information?

Tags: dns

If I clear DNS cache and remove DNS server information, how can I ping to a specific site?

Comment: Without knowing the IP address?

Comment: Just ping the IP address. If you don't know the IP address you can't do it without DNS.

Comment: I know ip address and domain name, but if I have to use domain name without dns. can I?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSI layer-4 are explicitly off-topic here, as are questions about host configurations. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network, or on [su] for a personal network.

Answer (score 1):

Use the entry in the hosts file for your operating system.

Windows:

```
c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Linux:

```
/etc/hosts
```

Add a record like:

```
192.168.0.1 my.domain.sample
```

Comment: Still, you need to know the IP address.